# Oritentation issue in landscape (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation, uinavigationbar, landscape

Good day!

I have a view which i forcefully landscape. but the problem which i am facing is that the navigation bar buttons are somewhere else but i have to click few steps (inches) back to let it act. e.g.

if button is at frame

0,0 then i have to click at 50,0 to go back. i am attaching screenshot, if some one could help me in this. Please help

Thanks & Regards
[image: Image Attached with detailed explanation]

Comment: does it also happen for the button on the right?

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the code (or the entire project), it is unlikely for anyone to tell you exactly what is wrong.

...Unless this is just a frame/bounds issue. Make sure they are set to the proper values. The frame is the area where your view is displayed, and the bounds is the area where your view will accept interaction.

Answer (score 0):

How did you force the screen in landscape? The usual way is something like the following (in any UIViewController subclass):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

If you forced it any other way, that might be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may cause due to no Auto resizing You will only have to do is goto **Layout** in **Interface Builder** then **Live Auto resizing**.

*OR*

By selecting all the components one by one hit **cmd+3** Then there is a panel named autoresizing only select lines in inner square and deselect outer one if any

Only then your missing block will be shown and no button problem will be there

Cheers